# error message when trying to write a sequence

Tags: sql

i am trying to write the following sequence

```
INSERT INTO cruise (cruise_id, cruise_name)
VALUES (SEQ_CRUISE_ID.NEXTVAL, 'hawaii and back');
```

but when I execute it, I receive an error message. I do have privileges to execute the command. I appreciate any help and suggestions on this one

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) edit your question and the error message as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the error message so we can have more insight into the issue? The only issue found is that this db collection might not exist. Can you confirm if table in question exists?

```
table: cruise
```

Comment: error ORA-02289

Comment: One thing, Make sure the sequence name is correct, and that you have the right to perform the desired operation on this sequence.

Comment: You can use the comments to be clarified about the question. Don't use answers for that...